# How to merge Spark dataframes by id?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a dataframe x containing: id, C.

Suppose I have a dataframe y containing: A, B, id.

How do I find the row in dataframe y where the id is the same and merge everything in y.

The result should be:

```
DataFrame:[A,B,C,id]
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
>>> merged = x.join(y, "id")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
merged = x.join(y, y.id==x.id)
```

Use drop() to remove unnecessary columns.